# Consuming IIS Hosted WCF Application with multiple endpoints

Tags: wcf

I have two endpoints in a service (WCFTestLibarary) which implements two different contracts. I have hosted this Service in IIS under the Application name WCFServiceAPP.

```
 < service behaviorConfiguration="WCFTestLibrary.Service1Behavior"
        name="WCFTestLibrary.Service1">  
         < endpoint address="/MyService" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFTestLibrary.IService1" > 
           < identity>  
            < dns value="localhost" />
          < /identity>
        < /endpoint>
        < endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        < endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WCFTestLibrary.IMicrosoft" address="/Microsoft" />
        < /service>
```

I am able to browse my service from IIS with the URL http://localhost/WCFServiceAPP/WCFTestLibrary.Service1.svc

When i am trying to access 
http://localhost/WCFServiceAPP/WCFTestLibrary.Service1.svc/MyService or/ Microsoft 
i am getting bad request error.

Comment: Does your Service1 implement both IMicrosoft and IService1? Try to add a service reference in a client app and see if it works

Comment: Rajesh,                                                                   Thanks for your reply. Yes i am implemeting both Serive contract(IMicrosoft,IService) in Service1 by Partial class. After publishing the WCF in IIS, when i try to browse the service from IIS http://localhost/WCFServiceAPP/WCFTestLibrary.Service1.Svc/MyService i am getting bad request error.

Comment: Can you try removing one endpoint and make sure at least one works fine and then add the other. Also in the address attribute of each endpoint element can you just specify the address without a slash at the beginning.